# how to Style gridview rows during runtime in wpf?

Tags: wpf

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="اسم الشركة" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=company_name}" Width="200" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="رمز الشركة" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=symbol}" Width="Auto" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="سعر السهم"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=price}" Width="Auto" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="نسبة التغير" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=change_percent}" Width="Auto" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

I have the previous XAML tags to define the listview I am using in my wpf - C# application
I want to give each row in my listview a specific color that would be chosen during runtime

I know it might be a silly question but I need it badly and I have looked for it alot with no results

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://dotnetlearning.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/highlight-selected-item-listview-gridview-listviewitem/) something you are looking for?

Comment: actually its not , I have to find out something that can work with my XA<L code overthere